# C# How to get two pictureboxes to intersect?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox, intersection

I have an appointment for school in Visual Studio. I am working on a game. I have made 2 picture boxes. One is the runner, the other is the obstacle. I want to have an action when the runner and the obstacle intersect. Therefor I have written an pice of code, does someone know what is wrong about this code, and why it is not working? It isn't that the aren't intersecting.

```
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnStart.Visible = false;
            TmrObject.Start();
            
            if (PbObstakel1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PbPoppetje.Bounds))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ur dead");
            }
        }
```

And this is the code in the timer:

```
private void TmrObject_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PbObstakel1.Location = new Point(PbObstakel1.Location.X - 5, PbObstakel1.Location.Y);
        }
```

Comment: Your intersection code will be executed when you click the button. Presumably you want to check that when your picturebox(s) moves(changing location). So in the case here it should be checked in the Timer event where you change the location and in all the other spot where you change the location(s).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ralf:

```
private void TmrObject_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PbObstakel1.Location = new Point(PbObstakel1.Location.X - 5, PbObstakel1.Location.Y);
        
    if (PbObstakel1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PbPoppetje.Bounds))
    {
        TmrObject.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Ur dead");
    }
}
```